# Can giving input too early cause glitches?

Tags: python, windows, loops, input, undefined-behavior

Suppose that my Python code looks like this:

```
While(True):
    Var = input()
    Do something
```

I noticed that when I run this from a Windows prompt, I can give input while the `Do something` is still running. For example:

1. If I press enter during `Do something`, then the next time that input is asked the `Var` is automatically assigned empty input.
2. If I press something else (like `1`) during `Do something`, then the next time that input is asked I see this in my prompt. So it says `1`, and I can still choose to delete it, add something to it or press enter.
3. If can also make combinations of these. If I press `1`, `enter`, `1`, `enter` during `Do something`, then the next two loops will start automatically with `Var = 1`.

This seems a bit strange and potentially nonintended. Is it possible that the algorithm will behave different/strangely/undefined if I give certain inputs during `Do something`?

(Note that `Do something` uses the value of `Var`)

Comment: This is normal behavior. It doesn't affect code that doesn't interact with the standard input or the console application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely intended. It is not specific to Python, it's how terminal input works: Whatever you type in goes into a *buffer,* and is held there until the running program chooses to read it. Then it will be read in strict sequence -- as long as you are typing at the command line, there is no chance that some of your input could be read out of order. And the input buffer is quite large, so you have to do a lot of type-ahead before your input is lost or rejected.

Actually there are buffers in multiple places. What you type is not even delivered to your program until you hit Enter-- that's line-buffering at the terminal interface. But I trust this has answered your question.